# How to make a bind file from route53 API using AWS Boto3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto, amazon-route53, boto3

I wanted to create a dns_hosted_zone backup BIND File using Boto3.
I am using the following script to list all resource record sets:

```
     hosted_zones = conn.list_hosted_zones()['HostedZones']
     for hosted_zone in hosted_zones:
          domain_name = hosted_zone["Name"]
          zone_id = hosted_zone["Id"]
          record_sets = conn.list_resource_record_sets(HostedZoneId=zone_id)
          record_sets = record_sets["ResourceRecordSets"]
          for record in record_sets:
              print record
```

But I wanted to convert these RR's to BIND format and save them in a file.
Is there any way to convert those resource records (RR's) in BIND format using python library.
If Yes,How and If no,any alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

You wouldnt need a library per se. Just use a standard template for a zone file and then fill in those values with those got from your "record" set.

A sample zone file could be as below:

$ORIGIN example.com.

$TTL 86400

@   IN  SOA dns1.example.com.   hostmaster.example.com. (
            2001062501 ; serial
            21600      ; refresh after 6 hours
            3600       ; retry after 1 hour
            604800     ; expire after 1 week
            86400 )    ; minimum TTL of 1 day

```
IN  NS  dns1.example.com.       
IN  NS  dns2.example.com.        


IN  MX  10  mail.example.com.       
IN  MX  20  mail2.example.com.
```

dns1    IN  A   10.0.1.1
dns2    IN  A   10.0.1.2

server1 IN  A   10.0.1.5
server2 IN  A   10.0.1.6

ftp IN  A   10.0.1.3
    IN  A   10.0.1.4

mail    IN  CNAME   server1
mail2   IN  CNAME   server2

www IN  CNAME   server1